# Memory Error in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am running a Jupyter Notebook but I run into a memory error when I get to this line:

`X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42, test_size=0.1)`

The `train_test_split` function is from sklearn. If I shut down all processes except for the notebook it gets further through the program but still throws a Memory Error before completing the program. I am running 64 bit Python and when I run `free -m` I get the following output:

`total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7877        2318        3925         512        1633        4719
Swap:           255           6         249`

The data set is only 2.5 MB so I don't think I should be getting a Memory Error and I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating the swap file from the terminal to temporarily increase virtual memory manually.

Example:

```
sudo swapoff -a
sudo fallocate -l 5G /swapfile5g
sudo mkswap /swapfile5g
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile5g
sudo swapon /swapfile5g
```